# Where can I find information on forming spirit pacts?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e

I have been reading over the Book of Spirits and it mentioned some form of trade that normal humans could make with Spirits for favors and such. Unfortunately, the page referenced in the book to find out more details is not a page that has these details.

Is there another book I can reference that would help me with the details of Spirit Pacts? Also, and what they would trade for what or is this simply up to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want hard mechanics, I believe the best option is chapter 5, "Otherworldly Compacts," of *Summoners* for Mage: the Awakening. These rules are similar to the Changeling rules for pledges or contracts (I forget which) or the Demon rules for pacts.

You select a bunch of benefits, costs, and details and balance out their points.

Costs are things like access to the world, your body, or your soul; a task you perform for the spirit; avoiding some action the spirit dislikes; sacrificing your blood, an animal, or another human; or giving up a merit. There's also typically something severe that you forfeit if you break the terms of the compact.

If you don't want to use the formal compact system, you can certainly just do informal pacts trading something in the spirit's power for something the spirit wants (typically something that will give it Essence or make it easier to get Essence).

Comment: I actually just referenced that book and found out what you were talking about after I thought a moment. I got a lot of the books, and I didn't really think about the Mage Summoner book because in my mind it was more for the Supernal and not the Shadow. Thank you for the reply sir and giving me some examples. In the Book of Spirits it had mentioned while a mortal was trapped in the Shadow Realm and how he could get sustenance from them, but they never explained what was needed to get meat from an animal spirit assuming the human had no way to kill it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the part you are referring to is the spirits called "The Mercenary" I don't think there is a concept of "Spirit Pacts" with rules and such. Its all about motives. If a character is desperate or greedy and needs supernatural help, and also knows how to contact spirits, either by medium, occult powers or directly in physical world, he might struck a deal with the spirit.

In the book's example, a spirit with the power to possess mortals could help another human being by possessing his enemies and such. But don't limit yourself with possession. Spirit's can influence the physical world with "Reach" numen. They also can manipulate objects/people/feelings/concepts of their purview. A night club owner could send an anger/murder spirit to his rivals club to cause terror, which ultimately disrupts his rivals business.

There are so many things a mortal could ask from a spirit. but what about the spirits? what do *they* want? well first of all they need essence to survive, and essence is not always abundant. Spirits regain their lost essence by being in the proximity of their purview. So a love spirit could gain essence just by attending a romantic dinner. mortals can setup the scene for the spirit so the spirit could gain essence. for other spirits, they might have enemies in the physical world, like werewolves which try to kill or mages which try to control them. the mortal could be used by the spirit to eliminate or disable his enemies.

suppose a nature spirit was happy and all in a park, but suddenly, construction vehicles barge in and begin destroying the trees which is the source of essence for the spirit. So the spirit sends message (with reach numen) to a nearby mortal to stop the construction of a new mall on the park. the mortal asks for a magical night with his girlfriend in the park after this issue is resolved. the deal is struck and the mortal organizes environmentalists to protest the construction and see where this goes.

Comment: Hey Volkan thanks for this information, definitely added some plot elements. I was more curious as well how they communicated and if there was some song or dance that needed to be performed. Also, just mechanics wise, so a guy wants to be stronger from a bull spirit what would be required for such a favor. But definitely helpful. :) Thank you

Comment: A spirit can communicate with beings in the physical world if they possess appropriate numen. for mortals its harder, but not impossible. they can cross the gauntlet if they manage to find a verge and talk to spirits there, if the spirit knows mortal language of course. mortals can also step into shadow realm with the help of other supernaturals like mages and werewolves. lastly a mortal can make his body suitable for possession by attracting spirits (like a wrath spirit by being noticable more wrathful) and talk to other mortals through the victim. dancing might surely attract dance spirits.